# Como puedo encontrar un elemento dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, booleano

tengo que hacer un ejercicio y sinceramente no me sale. 
Me gustaría saber si alguien me podría decir en que estoy errando, como seria la solución y por que? 
El ejercicio dice:

Comprueba si el elemento existe dentro de "array"
 Devuelve "true" si está, o "false" si no está
 Mi código:

```
function arrayContiene(array, elemento) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (elemento == array)
  } return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Te falta especificar el elemento del array a comparar dentro del ciclo `array[i]` y, además, tienes el return fuera del if.

También puedes usar el método `includes()` disponible para arrays.

```js
let myArr = [1, 3, 5, 7];

function arrayContiene(array, elemento) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (elemento == array[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(arrayContiene(myArr, 4)); // Falso
console.log(arrayContiene(myArr, 5)); // Verdadero

// Con método nativo includes()
console.log(myArr.includes(2)); // Falso
console.log(myArr.includes(7)); // Verdadero
```

Comment: Gracias, la verdad me ayudaste muchísimo, porque no sabia en que estaba errando!

Answer (score -1):

```
function arrayContiene(array, elemento) {
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (elemento == array[i])
  } return true;
```

Comment: Gracias! Me ayudo bastante!

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer] y a [edit] tu respuesta para agregar comentarios relevantes que la complementen. Saludos

Comment: amigo, es algo simple, no hay que escribir tanto xD, con que el vea el codigo vera la diferencia, y sabra que solo le faltaba el [i]

Comment: No todos saben de programación... Algunos están empezando. Podrías explicar el funcionamiento del `[i]` en un bucle, por ejemplo.